Literal programming-like management of documentation and release notes in a single file in pandoc?
In literal programming, a literate program combines code and prose (documentation) in one file format: in this example, a hello.w file contains both code and Latex text -- then ctangle hello.w is used to generate a compilable hello.c C source code file, while cweave hello.w is used to generate the documentation hello.tex.
I already use pandoc to write documentation, which I then export to PDF via Latex. At the same time, I separately manage a RELEASE_NOTES.md file, which takes up its own time.
Now, I would like to cut down on the time needed to manage RELEASE_NOTES.md, so I thought about managing both documentation and release notes in a single Markdown file, similar to how code and documentation is managed in a single file in literate programming. In essence, what I would want is:

The single file should be usable as the direct source of main documentation, as in pandoc doc_rn_main.md -o doc.pdf (although I wouldn't mind a preprocessing step, either)
For release notes, it should be possible to use pandoc for markdown to markdown conversion, probably using some special command line arguments, to obtain a release notes markdown file, as in pandoc [arguments] doc_rn_main.md -o RELEASE_NOTES.md

I am not aware of an existing feature for this kind of thing in pandoc - if I missed it, I'd love to know about it.
Otherwise, in terms of Markdown for pandoc, I guess this question reduces to:

How can I label or mark a set of paragraphs (Markdown text), in a way that allows for nested labels?
How can I associate a small snippet of text to the paragraph(s) label, intended as an entry for release notes?

Below is a pseudocode illustration of what I would imagine would end up in the main source document, let's call it doc_rn_main.md - I have recently learned about Org mode markup (via https://github.com/limist/literate-programming-examples), which I think is appropriate here, however I doubt it is supported by pandoc (and therefore, the below is pseudocode):
# Introduction

MyApp is a program that allows the user to perform some important tasks.

# Starting

Start the MyApp program by double-clicking its icon.

# Device list

Click the "Device list" button in MyApp, to show a list of available devices in the main table.

#+BEGIN_SORT_DEVICE_LIST_FEATURE
#rn-ver:v1.01
#rn-date:2024-04-12
#begin-rn-entry
* Added "Sort" entry in right-click context menu of main device list table
#end-rn-entry

## Device list sorting

Right-click on the main table, and choose "Sort" from the context menu, to sort the device list shown in the table by name, ascending.

#+BEGIN_SORT_DEVICE_LIST_OPTIONS_FEATURE
#rn-ver:v1.02
#begin-rn-entry
* Added "Ascending" and "Descending" submenu entries, for the "Sort" right-click context menu of main device list table
#end-rn-entry

* Hover over the "Sort" menu, to show a submenu with two options: "Ascending" and "Descending"; click any of these to have the device list shown in the main table sorted accordingly
#+END_SORT_DEVICE_LIST_OPTIONS_FEATURE
#+END_SORT_DEVICE_LIST_FEATURE

## Closing the application

Click the X in the upper right corner of the MyApp application window, to close the application.

#+BEGIN_SAVE_CSV_ON_CLOSE_FEATURE
#rn-ver:v1.01
#rn-date:2024-04-12
#begin-rn-entry
* Added automatic saving of main device list table as `MyApp.csv` file upon application close.
#end-rn-entry

Note that when you close the application, the contents of the main device list table will be automatically saved as a CSV file, `MyApp.csv`, in the same directory where the `MyApp` executable is located.

#+END_SAVE_CSV_ON_CLOSE_FEATURE

#+BEGIN_INITIAL_RELEASE
#rn-ver:v1.00
#begin-rn-entry

* Found devices can be listed in the main table shown in the application, by clicking the "Device list" button. 

#end-rn-entry
#+END_INITIAL_RELEASE

#+BEGIN_RELEASE_DATE_TABLE
v1.00 , 2023-12-21
v1.01 , 2024-03-14
v1.02 , 2024-04-12
#+END_RELEASE_DATE_TABLE

Then, to generate release notes, I'd imagine running something like pandoc [release-note-arguments] doc_rn_main.md -o RELEASE_NOTES.md, and in the resulting RELEASE_NOTES.md, I'd have:
# MyApp Release Notes

## v1.02 - Fri, 2024 Apr 12 

* Added "Ascending" and "Descending" submenu entries, for the "Sort" right-click context menu of main device list table

## v1.01 - Thu, 2024 Mar 14 

* Added "Sort" entry in right-click context menu of main device list table
* Added automatic saving of main device list table as `MyApp.csv` file upon application close.

## v1.00 (initial release) - Thu, 2023 Dec 21

* Found devices can be listed in the main table shown in the application, by clicking the "Device list" button. 

Then, to generate the main documentation, I'd imagine running something like pandoc [main-document-arguments] doc_rn_main.md -o doc.md (which I would then convert to PDF via pandoc doc.md -o doc.pdf), and in the resulting doc.md, I'd have:
# Introduction

MyApp is a program that allows the user to perform some important tasks.

# Starting

Start the MyApp program by double-clicking its icon.

# Device list

Click the "Device list" button in MyApp, to show a list of available devices in the main table.

## Device list sorting

Right-click on the main table, and choose "Sort" from the context menu, to sort the device list shown in the table by name, ascending.

* Hover over the "Sort" menu, to show a submenu with two options: "Ascending" and "Descending"; click any of these to have the device list shown in the main table sorted accordingly

## Closing the application

Click the X in the upper right corner of the MyApp application window, to close the application.

Note that when you close the application, the contents of the main device list table will be automatically saved as a CSV file, `MyApp.csv`, in the same directory where the `MyApp` executable is located.

The above pseudocode example demonstrates:

The general flow of main source file doc_rn_main.md is preserved in the output documentation file doc.md, even with nested release note marks - however the release notes document is sorted by release date, descending
All paragraphs that are not otherwise marked are considered to be a part of "initial release"
Release note marks without any documentation content (like the one for "initial release") can also be used to document features that are removed in later releases (so they still show in release notes, but do not show in the documentation)
Correlation between release versions and dates is kept as a separate item, so there is less work to do if you copy-paste the wrong release date for a version

So, is there an existing facility in pandoc that would allow me to do something like this - and if not, what would be the appropriate way to implement something like this?
(About "appropriate" - after finishing writing the above example, I realized that if I use something like MarkText to get a quick preview of the main source file doc_rn_main.md, I will get a whole lotta #rn-ver: stuff printed, which I would not want, as it increases cognitive load - so it would probably be better to implement these release note markings via Markdown (HTML) comments, so they are invisible; and this would also probably help with getting rid of the markdown documentation generation step pandoc [main-document-arguments] doc_rn_main.md -o doc.md, as we could compile PDF directly from the main source file, e.g. pandoc doc_rn_main.md -o doc.pdf)

The "pandoc-way" would be to use a Lua filter in combination with "fenced divs".
# Device list

Click the "Device list" button in MyApp, to show a list of
available devices in the main table.

::: {.release-note version="v1.01" date="2024-04-12"}
Added "Sort" entry in right-click context menu of main device list table
:::

Two filters would be required, one for the production of the main document, and one for the release notes.  The filter for the main doc would be simple, as it would just remove the release notes:
function Div (div)
  if div.classes:includes 'release-note' then
    return {}  -- delete div
  end
end

Use with pandoc --lua-filter=remove-release-notes.lua ....
Writing a filter to collect and sort the release notes would be a bit more involved. If you run into problems writing that filter, and if you have specific questions, then you can ask either here or on the pandoc discussions board.
